# Arduino SD library directory naming rules

Tags: c++, arduino, storage, fat32

I want to create some directories that represent dates, for example "11.03.24" but it seems like the SD.mkdir() function return false whenever I use special characters in my path. Strangely enough, the SD succeeds to make the directories that have only 1 special character in their naming like "@/fasdaf/".
It is allowed to use special characters in the SD library?

```
void setup() {

  // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
  }


  Serial.print("Initializing SD card...");

  if (!SD.begin(8)) {
    Serial.println("initialization failed!");
   return;
  }
  Serial.println("initialization done.");

if(SD.mkdir("vdfa/3143#2123/fasfd")){ 
    Serial.println("Succesfully created directory");
    }
if(SD.mkdir("!")){
    Serial.println("Succesfully created directory1");
    }
    if(SD.mkdir("@")){
    Serial.println("Succesfully created directory2");
    }
    if(SD.mkdir("#")){
    Serial.println("Succesfully created directory3");
    }
    if(SD.mkdir("$")){
    Serial.println("Succesfully created directory4");
    }
    if(SD.mkdir("%")){
    Serial.println("Succesfully created directory5");
    }
    if(SD.mkdir("^")){
    Serial.println("Succesfully created directory6");
    }
    if(SD.mkdir("&")){
    Serial.println("Succesfully created directory7");
    }
    if(SD.mkdir("*")){
    Serial.println("Succesfully created directory8");
    }

  void loop(){

}
```

I get "Succesfully created" for 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, and 7 but not on the first one were the code works without that special character included

Comment: Why make problems for yourself with awkward/difficult names? Go with the flow! https://superuser.com/a/661729

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save dates, use standarts:

```
DD_MM_YY (or any combination)
DD-MM-YY (or any combination)
DDMMYY (or any combination)
```

or, as Mark Setchell posted, use any symbols that are **NOT** listed on that page.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem, when I was inserting those characters into my strings the characters themselves were not the problem but the max folder length which is 8 characters and I was exceeding it. Now everything is ok, Cheers!